# Show that $\int_0^1 h(t)dt\geq\left(\int_0^1 f(t)dt \right)^a\left(\int_0^1 g(t)dt \right)^{1-a}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Let $ a \in (0,1)$ and $f,g,h :[0,1]\to (0,\infty)$ be continuous functions satisfying
$h(ax+(1-a)y)\geq f(x)^ag(y)^{1-a}$ for all $x,y \in [0,1]$.

Prove that
$$ \int_0^1 h(t)dt\geq\left(\int_0^1 f(t)dt  \right)^a\left(\int_0^1 g(t)dt  \right)^{1-a} $$

I tried integrating left side with respect to $x$ and $y$ separately, but it didn't work.

Edit: Number '$a$' is chosen only once, the condition does not have to hold for values of '$a$' other then the one we chose.

Comment: A big part of getting this one, is to be recognizing  which region of the given inequality is going to be relevant in proving the desired inequality; the desired inequality only involves equal input values, so you should reinterpret the given inequality as it applies on the line y=x.

Comment: @rulergraham can you please tell us the source of this problem?

Comment: @ShubhrajitBhattacharya It's a problem from my Calculus class, but I missed presentation of the solution. Nevertheless, I didn't see it on math-stack exchanhe, so I thought I can post it here.

Comment: Do you know the definition of logarithmically convex\concave function ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the Prékopa–Leindler inequality (see e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%A9kopa%E2%80%93Leindler_inequality)). Also [here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/tag/prekopa-leindler-inequality/)

**Edit:**
The proof that can be found in the paper of [Gardner](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2002-39-03/S0273-0979-02-00941-2/home.html), in the setting of the OP, is at the level of a Calculus class.
Let us consider the functions
$$
F(u) := \int_0^u f(x)\, dx,
\qquad
G(u) := \int_0^u g(x)\, dx,
\qquad u \in [0,1].
$$
Since $f,g$ are continuous and strictly positive functions, we have that $F$ and $G$ are continuously differentiable and strictly increasing, with $F' = f$ and $G' = g$.
If we set $F_1 := F(1)$, $G_1 := G(1)$, then $F$ is a bijection from $[0,1]$ to $[0, F_1]$ and $G$ is a bijection from $[0,1]$ to $[0, G_1]$.
Let $u,v\colon [0,1] \to [0,1]$ be the functions defined by
$$
u(t) := F^{-1}(F_1\, t),
\qquad
v(t) := G^{-1}(G_1\, t),
\qquad t\in [0,1].
$$
Since $u'(t) = F_1 / f(u(t))$ and $v'(t) = G_1 / g(v(t))$ for every $t\in [0,1]$, using the AM-GM inequality we deduce that
$$
w'(t) := a\, u'(t) + (1-a)\, v'(t)
\geq [u'(t)]^a [v'(t)]^{1-a} =
\frac{F_1^a}{f(u(t))^a}\cdot \frac{G_1^{1-a}}{g(v(t))^{1-a}}
$$
and finally
$$
\int_0^1 h(x)\, dx = \int_0^1 h(w(t))\, w'(t)\, dt
\geq \int_0^1 f(u(t))^a g(v(t))^{1-a} \frac{F_1^a}{f(u(t))^a}\cdot \frac{G_1^{1-a}}{g(v(t))^{1-a}}\, dt
= F_1^a G_1^{1-a}.
$$

Comment: Great finding @Rigel

Comment: More elementary does not always mean easier :D

Comment: ... but for sure also this proof is elegant

Answer (score 3):

As we will see,  **(a)** there is nothing particular about the choice of the interval $[0,1]$. The result holds if the condition holds in an interval $I$, bounded or unbounded; **(b)** continuity is not crucial  here. However we assume that $f$ and $g$ are measurable functions such that $f^{-1}(U)+g^{-1}(U)$ is  measurable whenever $U$ is a Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Certainly this is satisfied when $f$ and $g$ are continuous, and more generally when $f$ and $g$ are Borel measurable (in this case $f^{-1}(U)+g^{-1}(U)$ is universally measurable).

---

Some notation first.  For any function $\Phi:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ and $t\geq0$, we denote $\{\Phi>t\}=\{x\in[0,1]: \Phi(x)>t\}$; for any set $A\subset\mathbb{R}$, and $b\in\mathbb{R}$, $bA=\{ba:a\in A\}$; For any sets $A,B\subset\mathbb{R}$, $A+B=\{a+b:a\in A, b\in B\}$.

- The first claim is that
  $$a \{f>t\} +(1-a)\{g>t\}\subset\{h>t\}\tag{1}\label{one}$$
  To check this, notice that if $u$ belongs to the set in the left-hand side of $\eqref{one}$ then $u=ax+(1-a)y$ for some $x\in \{f>t\}$ and $y\in\{g>t\}$ and so, $h(u)\geq f(x)^ag^{1-a}(y)>t^a t^{1-a}=t$.
- By Brunn–Minkowski's inequality and the homogeneity of Lebesgue's measure $\lambda$ (on $\mathbb{R}$)
  \begin{aligned}
  \lambda(\{h>t\})&\geq \lambda\big(a\{f>t\} +(1-a)\{g>t\}\big)\\
  &\geq\lambda(a\{f>t\})+\lambda((1-a)\{g>t\})\\
  &=a\lambda(\{f>t\})+(1-a)\lambda(\{g>t\})
  \end{aligned}
- Fubuni's theorem leads to
  \begin{aligned}
  \int^1_0h(s)\,ds&=\int^\infty_0\lambda(\{h>t\})\,dt\\
  &\geq a\int^\infty_0\lambda(\{f>t\})\,dt + (1-a) \int^\infty_0\lambda(\{g>t\})\,dt \\
  &= a\int^1_0f(s)\,ds + (1-a)\int^1_0 g(s)\,ds
  \end{aligned}
- Finally, by the arithmetic--geometric inequality ($a\,\alpha+ (1-a)\,\beta\geq \alpha^a\beta^{1-a}$)

\begin{aligned}
\int^1_0h(s)\,ds\geq  a\int^1_0f(s)\,ds + (1-a)\int^1_0 g(s)\,ds
\geq\Big(\int^1_0 f(s)\,ds\Big)^a\big(\int^1_0 g(s)\,ds\Big)^{1-a}
\end{aligned}

---

**Edit:** We have used a big result, namely the Brunn-Minksowki inequality. In the real line however, this result may be proven without much effort. Here is a short proof.

**Brunn-Minkowski's inequality on $\mathbb{R}$.** Suppose $A,B\subset\mathbb{R}$ are measurable subsets such that $A+B$ is measurable. Then
$$\lambda(A+B)\geq \lambda(A) +\lambda(B)\tag{2}\label{two}$$

*Proof:* It suffices to assume that both $\lambda(A)$ and $\lambda(B)$ are finite. Due to the  inner regularity of Lebesgue's measure, it is enough to show that  $\eqref{two}$ holds for $A$ and $B$ compact. If $a^*:=\sup A$ and $b_*:=\inf B$ then
$$ A+B\subset (a^*+B)\cup(A+ b_*)\supset\{a^*+b_*\}$$
If $x\in (a^*+B)\cap(A+ b_*)$ then for some $(a,b)\in A\times B$,
$x=a^*+b=b_*+a$. Since $0\leq a^*-a=b_*-b\leq0$, it follows that $a=a^*$ and $b=b_*$ and so, $x=a^*+b_*$. Thus
\begin{aligned}
\lambda(A+B)&\geq \lambda\big((a^*+B)\cup(A+b_*)\big)\\
&=\lambda((a^*+B)+\lambda(A+b_*)-\lambda(\{a^*+b^*\})=\lambda(A)+\lambda(B)
\end{aligned}

---

**Notes:**

- The result can be generalized to higher dimensions starting from the one dimensional case and proceeding by induction with the help of Fubini's theorem.
- The higher dimensional versions of  Brunn-Minkowski's inequality can be obtained form the  high dimensional version of  Prékopa–Leindler's theorem.

---

**Thanks to Rigel** for the reminder of the aforementioned result which in turn reminded me of the Brunn–Minkowski inequality.

I still would like to know how **rulergraham's** teacher proved the statement in his Calculus class. A much simpler (but wickedly tricky) argument perhaps?

Comment: Thanks for writing the solution and the details. It applies directly to any interval [a,b] right ? ( maybe one could also obtain generalization via a change of variables in the final result for [0,1] )

Comment: It could be of interest a beautiful review paper by R. Gardner, freely available at https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2002-39-03/S0273-0979-02-00941-2/home.html

Comment: Yes Oliver that is what I was observing mine was more of a comment rather than a question ;)