# Sum of measures is less than measure of sum

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am asked to solve the following exercise: let $A,B$ be Lebesgue measurable subsets of the real line. Prove that $$\lambda(A) + \lambda(B) \leq \lambda(A+B).$$

I am aware of a related question, but that only pertains to finding a counter example so that equality does not hold. A standard example being $A = \mathbb{Z}$ and $B= [0,1],$ with $A+B = \mathbb{R}$.

What I’ve tried: I’ve found that it suffices to assume $A$ and $B$ have finite, nonzero measure, since these cases are trivial. I’ve also found that we may assume that both sets contain $0$, which is probably useful. (The statement for general $A$, $B$ then follows by translation invariance.)

Then I got stuck. Any hints or solutions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assuming that $A + B$ is notation for $A \cup B$ then if $A \subset B$ that statement is not true.

Comment: @user57 I would assume rather that $\ A+B=\{a+b\,|\,a\in A,b\in B\,\}\ .$

Comment: I indeed mean what @lonzaleggiera says, the sum of the elements

Comment: Look up Brunn-Minkowski inequality

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3726806/121671) is a short proof of the Brunn-Minkowski inequality for $\mathbb{R}$